# How to test an exception in a EJB

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb

I'm doing some junit tests in my application and I testing a validation method that is in my EJB.
I made a test for when the data pass and one test for when the method throw a exception.

This is my junits:

```
@Test(expected = ValidationException.class)
public void testValidationError() {
    service.validateCsvFile(createCsvContents(false));
}

@Test        
public void testValidationOk() {
    service.validateCsvFile(createCsvContents(true));
}
```

This is my method:

```
@Override
public void validateCsvFile(List<CSVDataRow> csvContents) throws MyException {
    List<String> repeatedTransactionIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> allTransactionIds = new HashSet<String>();
    for (CSVDataRow cSVDataRow : csvContents) {
        //performing a database size validation
        Validation<CSVDataRow> validation = Validator.validate(cSVDataRow);
        if (validation.hasViolations()){
            throw new ValidationException("Errors found for transactionId: " + cSVDataRow.getTransactionId(), validation.getErrorMessagesWithPropertyPath());
        }
        if (!allTransactionIds.add(cSVDataRow.getTransactionId())){
            repeatedTransactionIds.add(cSVDataRow.getTransactionId());
        }
    }

    if (!repeatedTransactionIds.isEmpty()){
        throw new ValidationException("Duplicated transactionIds found", repeatedTransactionIds.toString());
    }

}
```

The testValidationError junit do not pass.
It throws me this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<xxxxx.backend.exception.ValidationException> but was<javax.ejb.EJBException>
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you're running inside an EJB, which will always wrap with an EJBException by default.  You can, however, tell the container to throw the application exception, which I'll provide as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when an exception is thrown inside an EJB method the EJB container will wrap it with an [EJBException](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/ejb/EJBException.html).  You can, however, annotate your EJB method with [ApplicationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html), which will tell the EJB container to throw the application exception directly.

Comment: Thanks man. This resolved my problem. Thank you very much! PS. Just one question: Whats the difference between @ApplicationException(rollback = true) and @ApplicationException(rollback = false) ?

Comment: Np=) The rollback has to do with the context of your EJB, if it's within the context of a transaction or not.  For example, if your doing some operations with JMS or JPA and you do or don't want an Exception from this business method to cause a rollback on that transaction.